# Codeigniter: session class in routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

How can I access the codeigniter session class inside routes.php?

I need that class to route all the request (except /login) to a certain controller, unless the user has admin privileges (`$this->session->userdata('logged')`).

All the route rules are working, I only need to access that class.

Comment: why you want to use session class in routes page. define an default controller in routes and then within default controller's constructor check for login.

Comment: The problem is that I've already used MY_Controller for the admin backend.
I'm building a pre-launch countdown (all the urls must point to that page, except for the admin), and in my routes I added this (pseudocode):
`if (now > date of the launch || the user is admin) { normal navigation routes }
else { all routes must point to countdown, except login }`
The routes are working correctly, I only need a check for user privileges (stored in the admin)

Answer (score 0):

You are not typically able to access the Singleton ($this->) from the config & routes file because the classes are not loaded at that point

although there are a few workarounds to access the session, the better way would be to a MY_Controller & the _remap() function:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Here's some sample code that explains a little more about how they work:

http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/11/ci-_remap-function-the-friend-you-never-knew-you-had

Answer (score 0):

Create this `MY_Controller`and store it in `application/core/`, then have your other controllers extend it:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_check_auth();
}

private function _check_auth(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('is_admin')){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
}
```

Note: above code assumes you already have a user login system in place.

Comment: I can't use MY_Controller, it is used in the admin backend, please see the comment I added in the original post